# Obtaining order id in Order Detail Template

Tags: prestashop, smarty

Is there a way to get the id of the order that is opened in order-detail.tpl

I am using this function with a set id instead of order_id but i need to make it so depending on what order details page is opened order_id to be equal to the id of that order.

```
Product::eprim_carrier_status("order_id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear in which context you want to get the `order_id`. In `order-detail.tpl`, you have object `$order`, which is an instance of `OrderLazyArray`. So in smarty template you can get the order id like this: `$order.id_order`.

But probably the easiest way to get it is to take it from `$_GET` parameters, as every link to order detail page has the `id_order` parameter. For example, when you open any order detail page, the URL looks like this:
`http://yourprestasite.com/index.php?controller=order-detail&id_order=11`.
In Prestashop, you get both `$_GET` and `$_POST` parameters by using the `Tools::getValue('key')`. So in your case:

```php
 $id_order = Tools::getValue('id_order')
```